# HTTPS support in elastic search Jest client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, ssl, https, elasticsearch-jest

I am trying to connect elasticsearch through HTTPS connection [HTTPS/SSL support](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest).

the code is as follows

```
// trust ALL certificates
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        }).build();

        // skip hostname checks
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
        SchemeIOSessionStrategy httpsIOSessionStrategy = new SSLIOSessionStrategy(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);

        JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
        factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig.Builder("https://localhost:9200")
                        .defaultSchemeForDiscoveredNodes("https") // required, otherwise uses http
                        .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory) // this only affects sync calls
                        .httpsIOSessionStrategy(httpsIOSessionStrategy) // this only affects async calls
                        .build());            

        JestClient client = factory.getObject();

        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());                     
         Search search = new Search.Builder(searchSourceBuilder.toString())                
                .addIndex(INDEX)
                .addType(TYPE)                
                .setParameter(Parameters.SIZE, 2)
                .setParameter(Parameters.SCROLL, "5m")               
                .build();
             JestResult result = client.execute(search);
```

I am able to connect to using http connection. But when I try to connect using HTTPS connection ,I am getting following error

[image: Error]

Pls let me know if you figure out this error. Is there any problem with the code?

Comment: are you sure this is the error? The screenshot shows that Eclipse is not able to find the source code of RetryExec.class.

Comment: yes.. when client.excecute(search) is executed.. i get this screen. Is it some problem when trying to connect through https?